# Every minute for all day, but when Day Of Month is 2 and 7 need to trigger at 12:00AM-08:59AM and 11:00AM-11:59PM only

Tags: cron

I need to trigger every minute for Day 1, 3-16 and 18-31.
But need to trigger every minute between 12:00AM-08:59AM and 11:00AM-11:59PM for Day 2, 7.

```
Day 1   : Every minute
Day 2   : Every minute between 12:00AM-08:59AM and 11:00AM-11:59PM
Day 3   : Every minute
Day 4   : Every minute
Day 5   : Every minute
Day 6   : Every minute
Day 7   : Every minute
Day 8   : Every minute
Day 9   : Every minute
Day 10  : Every minute
Day 11  : Every minute
Day 12  : Every minute
Day 13  : Every minute
Day 14  : Every minute
Day 15  : Every minute
Day 16  : Every minute
Day 17  : Every minute between 12:00AM-08:59AM and 11:00AM-11:59PM
Day 18  : Every minute
Day 19  : Every minute
Day 20  : Every minute
Day 21  : Every minute
Day 22  : Every minute
Day 23  : Every minute
Day 24  : Every minute
Day 25  : Every minute
Day 26  : Every minute
Day 27  : Every minute
Day 28  : Every minute
Day 29  : Every minute
Day 30  : Every minute
Day 31  : Every minute
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to set this up as two jobs.  I am pretty sure it can't be done with one.

```
* *          1,3-16,18-31 * * myjob
* 0-8,11-23  2,17         * * myjob
```